# Java: Size of a Vector in bytes

Tags: java, android, vector, size

Is it possible to get the size of the Vector or ArrayList or any object for that matter in bytes in java? size() function gives only the number of elements. But I want to get the actual size of the object.

Comment: *"But I want to get the actual size of the object."*  Why?

Comment: yes its possible, provided you can calculate the bytes of individual object in that Vector/Array

Comment: Generally you don't need to know this, but if you really do the simplest thing to do is to use a memory profiler. e.g. the free VisualVM which comes with the JDK.

Comment: Take a look to Instrumentation interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Comment: @Andrew: I have some 12 Vector<String> objects. I want to see which one is occupying more space. Based on that I have to populate the vector. This is for an android app. I want to keep the app memory as small as possible.

Comment: we have sizeof() operator in c++. I expected a similar thing in Java. Perhaps there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I implemented my own for getting size.

```
long sizeof(ArrayList<String> list)
{
    long size = 0;
    for(String s: list)
        size+=s.length();
    return size;
}
```

Comment: It does not work like that... Each string has an overhead, the list itself has an overhead etc.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. He said size in bytes and didn't mention a String ArrayList, just objects.

Comment: @assylias: How big that overhead could affect the overall size of the list? I assume that the above code could give me good enough estimate on size of the object.

Comment: Hmmm... didn't realize you are the OP until now :P

Comment: @rahul: that gives you a reasonable estimate of the relative size of multiple such array lists. If that's all you need, then this is close enough, but it's **certainly not** the "size of a vector in bytes".

Comment: @rahul it depends on the JVM (dalvik in your case it seems). Admittedly, if you store list is large, the list overhead won't make much difference and if you strings are long, the string overhead won't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Different JDK having different size for the implicite objects.

You can count it by implicite object size multiply the length of the vector or arraylist. 
For Example if you declare a araylist of integer with 10 records in it, then
Java integers are 32 bits i.e. 32/8 = 4 bytes. 
You have 10 records hence 10x4 = 40 byetes.

in standard java byte = 8 bits, short=16bits, int=32bits, long=64bits.

Answer (score 0):

First : try to read [***Does Java have an operator like "sizeof()" in C***](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-12/02-qa-1226-sizeof.html)

Second : [**Try this code**](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html) :

```
public class Sizeof
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Warm up all classes/methods we will use
        runGC ();
        usedMemory ();
        // Array to keep strong references to allocated objects
        final int count = 100000;
        Object [] objects = new Object [count];

        long heap1 = 0;
        // Allocate count+1 objects, discard the first one
        for (int i = -1; i < count; ++ i)
        {
            Object object = null;

            // Instantiate your data here and assign it to object

            object = new Object ();
            //object = new Integer (i);
            //object = new Long (i);
            //object = new String ();
            //object = new byte [128][3]

            if (i >= 0)
                objects [i] = object;
            else
            {
                object = null; // Discard the warm up object
                runGC ();
                heap1 = usedMemory (); // Take a before heap snapshot
            }
        }
        runGC ();
        long heap2 = usedMemory (); // Take an after heap snapshot:

        final int size = Math.round (((float)(heap2 - heap1))/count);
        System.out.println ("'before' heap: " + heap1 +
                            ", 'after' heap: " + heap2);
        System.out.println ("heap delta: " + (heap2 - heap1) +
            ", {" + objects [0].getClass () + "} size = " + size + " bytes");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++ i) objects [i] = null;
        objects = null;
    }
    private static void runGC () throws Exception
    {
        // It helps to call Runtime.gc()
        // using several method calls:
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++ r) _runGC ();
    }
    private static void _runGC () throws Exception
    {
        long usedMem1 = usedMemory (), usedMem2 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; (usedMem1 < usedMem2) && (i < 500); ++ i)
        {
            s_runtime.runFinalization ();
            s_runtime.gc ();
            Thread.currentThread ().yield ();

            usedMem2 = usedMem1;
            usedMem1 = usedMemory ();
        }
    }
    private static long usedMemory ()
    {
        return s_runtime.totalMemory () - s_runtime.freeMemory ();
    }

    private static final Runtime s_runtime = Runtime.getRuntime ();
} // End of class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to show memory usage

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long m0 = rt.totalMemory() -  rt.freeMemory();
Object obj = new Object();      // create your object here
long m1 = rt.totalMemory() -  rt.freeMemory();
System.out.println(m1 - m0);
```

but it does not work. This works (at least on my PC)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object obj = createObject();
    long m0 = usedMem();
    long m1 = usedMem();
    obj = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        System.gc();
    m0 = usedMem();
    obj = createObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        System.gc();
    m1 = usedMem();
    System.out.println(m1 - m0);
}

private static long usedMem() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}

private static Object createObject() {
    return new Object();
}
```

if it prints `8` for new Object and `40` for new String() then it works correctly, then create your object and see its size

See more here http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html